# I'm trying to launch my qt application quickly on embedded linux

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I want to launch my qt application for less than 1s on embedded linux.

It's took 3~4s for launching qt application after start up embedded linux.

And then, when exit application and launch again, it's took 1s for launching application.

I used the following command.

./myapp -qws

How to first launch qt application for less than 1s on embedded linux?

Help me, thanks.

Comment: See this presentation, it helped me a lot: http://www.slideshare.net/andrewmurraympc/elce-the. Skip the beginning if you only need Qt app optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [prelink](http://linux.die.net/man/8/prelink) and [preload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preload_%28software%29).

Maybe you`ll want to try to use [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) instead of /tmp, so look at [howto](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/TmpOnTmpfs) and [reasons](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2012/05/msg01092.html).